# How do I delete a file from disk in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I delete a file from disk (unlink) in IntelliJ IDEA?

I am referring to the file that is currently open in the editor tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Navigate` | `Select In...` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) | **Project View**, <kbd>Del</kbd> or **Delete** from the context menu.

Or use `Refactor` | **Safe Delete** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>).